# Why is the RewriteBase not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Here is what I am trying to do:

> - domain is thinkingmonkey.me
> - domain has 127.0.0.1 as IP addr
> - *mod_alias* is installed.

I have a conf file called `directories.conf`. In which I have all the configuration pertaining to directories. `directories.conf` is included in `httpd.conf`

My `directories.conf` has

```
Alias /runs /xhprof/xhprof_html

<Directory /mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/.htaccess`. I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /runs
RewriteRule  .*  index.php
```

All I am trying to do is to direct any request under `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/` to `index.php`.

When I request for `thinkingmonkey.me/runs` **with no trailing slashes** I get `404 not found`.

So, I infer that `RewriteBase` is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing to `RewriteBase: /runs/`

Comment: @KristerAndersson that will not wok

Comment: index.php is in `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/` isn't it?

Comment: Try to add `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before the rewriteRule.

Comment: pardon for the delayed reply.
@regilero Yes, it is definitely present. Trying out `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ~ -d`

Answer (score -1):

Alias requires a tailing slash. Nothing to do with RewriteBase.

You could use a rewrite rule to add the slash when needed though. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^run$ /run/ [R=301,L]
```

Put this rule in the htaccess in the root of your server (not in `/xhprof/xhprof_html`)

Comment: the rule u have posted will just work for domain/run i.e. that ends with run, I am trying to redirect any requests through folder xhprof_html to index.php

Comment: Alias does not requires a trailing slash, it requires one in the second part if you had one in the first part. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey This only fixed the `domain/run` problem you were having. I assumed this was your only problem. Please rephrase I you have any additional problems.